# Mounting bar end mirrors on non-hollow bars?

Tags: motorcycle, aftermarket-upgrade, mirrors

I bought a CRG hindsight bar end mirror but the CRG adapters and all the adapters I find online seem to be for hollow bars.  But the bars on my 12 Yamaha R6 just have a threaded hole for a bolt.

Answer (score 2):

If your mirrors are these http://www.crgmoto.co.uk/crg-ls-hindsight-bar-end-mirror-27-p.asp

Then it looks like the way you mount them is to move all the controls inboard a bit and then clamp the mirrors on to the newly revealed handlebars.